# CSS dropdown menu advice

Tags: css

Hi I am trying to change the dropdown menu on my site so that it drops down directly under the link and also displays (when hovered over) the second level categories to the side instead of vertical

here is the code

```
/**
* Wide drop-down menu
*/



/* 1st level only
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#nav > li:hover > a { position: relative; z-index: 1; /* Pull up above     drop-down box */ }

/* 2nd level only
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* 2nd-level links block: with subcategory title and a list of child       categories */
#nav ul.level0 > li {
display:inline-block;
float:none;
vertical-align:top;
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:15px;
}
#nav ul.level0 > li > a {
margin-bottom:10px;
font-size:16px;
line-height:18px;
}

/* 2nd level+
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#nav ul li { /*float:none;*/ margin-bottom:1px; }
#nav ul li a { float:none; }

/* 3rd level only
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#nav ul.level1 { position:static; }
#nav ul.level1 > li {
float:none;
background:url(../../../images/infortis/ultra-megamenu/bullet.png) 3px     6px no-repeat;
padding-left:15px;
transition:         background-position 150ms ease-out;
-moz-transition:    background-position 150ms ease-out;
-webkit-transition: background-position 150ms ease-out;
-o-transition:      background-position 150ms ease-out;
}
#nav ul.level1 > li:hover { background-position:6px 6px; }

/* 4th level
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#nav ul.level2 { margin:7px 0; padding:0; position:static; }
#nav ul.level2 a { font-size:0.9166em; line-height:1.2727em;       /*11px       14px*/ opacity:0.6; }
#nav li.level2:hover ul.level2 a {
opacity:1;
transition:         opacity 150ms ease-out;
-moz-transition:    opacity 150ms ease-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity 150ms ease-out;
-o-transition:      opacity 150ms ease-out;
}

/* 4rd level+
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#nav ul ul ul li { background:none; padding-left:0; }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where's your HTML?

Comment: We'll need more code to get a better picture of what's going on. Maybe create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get an idea of what you want with the code you provided, but if you give your drop down menu an absolute position it should appear directly below the list item it is in.

Comment: Thanks that worked for the position thanks I am looking to make the sub menu's when hovered over appear in a small box to the right instead of expanding the menu vertical